# Error while loading FastCGI module in apache 2.2

Tags: apache, cgi, fastcgi

I'm using apache 2.2 (part of the xampp distribution) and I was trying to load my scripts written in lua using fastcgi, so I added to httpd.conf this:

LoadModule mod_fcgi modules/mod_fcgid.so

and now when I try to start apache I get the following error:

syntax error on line 530 of /xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf: Can't locate API module structure 'mod_fcgi' in the file /xampp/apache/modules/mod_fcgid.so: No error

The file is there and the path is correct, what does that error message mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be

```
LoadModule fcgid_module modules/mod_fcgid.so
```

Apache module structures are generally called foo_module, for a library called mod_foo.so. There's probably a reason for that, but I've no idea what it is :-)

Comment: It was that, thanks
by the way, this is really stupid design decision I lost a couple hours trying to fix it and then came here for help.